# Issue when trying to plot geom_tile using ggplotly

Tags: ggplot2, ggplotly

I would like to plot a ggplot2 image using ggplotly
What I am trying to do is to initially plot rectangles of grey fill without any aesthetic mapping, and then in a second step to plot tiles and change colors based on aesthetics. My code is working when I use ggplot but crashes when I try to use ggplotly to transform my graph into interactive

Here is a sample code

```
library(ggplot2)
library(data.table)
library(plotly)
library(dplyr)


  x = rep(c("1", "2", "3"), 3)
  y = rep(c("K", "B","A"), each=3)
  z = sample(c(NA,"A","L"), 9,replace = TRUE)

  df <- data.table(x,y,z)

  p<-ggplot(df)+
    geom_tile(aes(x=x,y=y),width=0.9,height=0.9,fill="grey") 


    p<-p+geom_tile(data=filter(df,z=="A"),aes(x=x,y=y,fill=z),width=0.9,height=0.9)
p
```

[image]

But when I type this

```
 ggplotly(p)
```

I get the following error

> Error in `[.data.frame`(g, , c("fill_plotlyDomain", "fill")) :
>   undefined columns selected

The versions I use are

```
> packageVersion("plotly")
```

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MXyHM.png) ‘4.7.1

```
packageVersion("ggplot2")
```

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MXyHM.png) ‘2.2.1.9000’

##########Edited example for Arthur

```
     p<-ggplot(df)+
    geom_tile(aes(x=x,y=y,fill="G"),width=0.9,height=0.9) 
  p<- p+geom_tile(data=filter(df,z=="A"),aes(x=x,y=y,fill=z),width=0.9,height=0.9)

  p<-p+ scale_fill_manual(
    guide = guide_legend(title = "test",
                         override.aes = list(
                           fill =c("red","white")                  )
    ),
    values = c("red","grey"),
    labels=c("A",""))
p
```

[image]

This works
but ggplotly(p) adds the grey bar labeled G in the legend

Comment: Hello! Is there any reason with you don't want to color directly through `aes(x=x,y=y, fill=z)` with a custom `+scale_fill_manual()`? (http://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/scale_manual.html)

Comment: Hi At the end this is what I do. But I want to hide the grey tile from the legend. Which again works with ggplot and correct use of  the guide_legend( override.aes)) and legend. But again when I use ggplotly the legend reappears

Comment: I added an example to explain better what I mean

Comment: So your real question is: "How to hide selected keys in the legend with ggplotly?" Do I understand you correctly?

Comment: For operational issues and requirements `scale_fill_manual` may not be always desired solution. Can we not create an issue in GitHub for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The output of the `ggplotly` function is a list with the `plotly` class. It gets printed as Plotly graph but you can still work with it as a list. Moreover, the [documentation](https://plot.ly/r) indicates that modifying the list makes it possible to clear [all](https://plot.ly/r/legend/#hiding-the-legend) or [part of](https://plot.ly/r/legend/#hiding-legend-entries) the legend. One only has to understand how the data is structured.

```
p<-ggplot(df)+
   geom_tile(aes(x=x,y=y,fill=z),width=0.9,height=0.9)+
   scale_fill_manual(values = c(L='grey', A='red'), na.value='grey')
p2 <- ggplotly(p)
str(p2)
```

The global legend is here in `p2$x$layout$showlegend` and setting this to false displays no legend at all.

The group-specific legend appears at each of the 9 `p2$x$data` elements each time in an other `showlegend` attribute. Only 3 of them are set to `TRUE`, corresponding to the 3 keys in the legend. The following loop thus clears all the undesired labels:

```
for(i in seq_along(p2$x$data)){
  if(p2$x$data[[i]]$legendgroup!='A'){
    p2$x$data[[i]]$showlegend <- FALSE
  }
}
```

Voilà!

Comment: And it worked! Merci!!!! This is really helpful an of course understanding the structure of the plotly object can help me with more manipulations I ll need in the future :)

Answer (score 0):

This works here:

```
ggplot(df)+
  geom_tile(aes(x=x,y=y,fill=z),width=0.9,height=0.9)+
  scale_fill_manual(values = c(L='grey', A='red'), na.value='grey')

ggplotly(p)
```

I guess your problem comes from the use of 2 different data sources, `df` and `filter(df,z=="A")`, with columns with the same name.

Answer (score 0):

***[Note this is not an Answer Yet]***
*(Putting for reference, as it is beyond the limits for comments.)*

The problem is rather complicated.

I just finished debugging the code of `plotly`. It seems like it's occurring [here](https://github.com/ropensci/plotly/blob/2cc296de6f77515003378a64b9fbdc93298ab45b/R/layers2traces.R#L849).

I have opened an issue in [GitHub](https://github.com/ropensci/plotly/issues/1562)

Here is the minimal code for the reproduction of the problem.

```r
library(ggplot2)

set.seed(1503)

df <- data.frame(x = rep(1:3, 3),
                 y = rep(1:3, 3),
                 z = sample(c("A","B"), 9,replace = TRUE), 
                 stringsAsFactors = F)

p1 <- ggplot(df)+
  geom_tile(aes(x=x,y=y, fill="grey"), color = "black")

p2 <- ggplot(df)+
  geom_tile(aes(x=x,y=y),fill="grey", color = "black")

class(plotly::ggplotly(p1))
#> [1] "plotly"     "htmlwidget"
class(plotly::ggplotly(p2))
#> Error in `[.data.frame`(g, , c("fill_plotlyDomain", "fill")): undefined columns selected
```